# oozie distcp s3 to s3 copy invalid arguments org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.HttpException

Tags: amazon-web-services, oozie, distcp

I have a distcp action as follows

```
 <action name="ExecuteDataCopyS3ToHDFS">
  <distcp xmlns="uri:oozie:distcp-action:0.2">
        <arg>-Dmapred.job.queue.name=dev</arg>
        <arg>-Dhadoop.security.credential.provider.path=jceks://hdfs/user/ABC/oneaws.jceks</arg>
        <arg>-update</arg>
        <arg>s3a://XXXX/</arg>
        <arg>s3n://XXXX/XXXX/</arg>
        </distcp>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="create-error-file" />
</action>
```

I added two credentials to the jceks file as follows

```
hadoop credential create fs.s3a.access.key -provider localjceks://file/home/XXX/oneaws.jceks
hadoop credential create fs.s3a.secret.key -provider localjceks://file/home/XXX/oneaws.jceks

hadoop credential create fs.s3n.access.key -provider localjceks://file/home/XXX/oneaws.jceks
hadoop credential create fs.s3n.secret.key -provider localjceks://file/home/XXX/oneaws.jceks
```

The s3a credential is for the source aws location and s3n credential is for the destination.

When i run the oozie action i get an exception and here is the stack trace.

```
 2016-12-15 17:31:21,933 ERROR [main] org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp: Invalid arguments: 
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: s3n://XXX/XXX/XXX
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.processException(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:449)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.processException(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:427)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.handleException(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:411)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadata(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:181)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:256)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:104)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.$Proxy28.retrieveMetadata(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.getFileStatus(NativeS3FileSystem.java:476)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1424)
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.setTargetPathExists(DistCp.java:217)
at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.run(DistCp.java:116)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:90)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.DistcpMain.run(DistcpMain.java:64)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:47)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.DistcpMain.main(DistcpMain.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:241)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1709)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
 Caused by: org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.HttpException
at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.performRequest(RestStorageService.java:519)
at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.performRequest(RestStorageService.java:281)
at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.performRestHead(RestStorageService.java:942)
at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.getObjectImpl(RestStorageService.java:2148)
at org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestStorageService.getObjectDetailsImpl(RestStorageService.java:2075)
at org.jets3t.service.StorageService.getObjectDetails(StorageService.java:1093)
at org.jets3t.service.StorageService.getObjectDetails(StorageService.java:548)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadata(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:174)
```

When i tested distcp from the commandline with the same credentials it works perfectly fine.

Comment: It turns out that distcp works just fine with these properties.  <arg>-Dfs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId=key</arg>
            <arg>-Dfs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey=secret</arg>. I am still unsure why it would not take the hadoop credential.

Answer (score 0):

The reason credential provider didn’t work for s3 or s3n was because it looks for pair fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId & fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey when you use s3n, not fs.s3n.access.key and fs.s3n.secret.key. It’s AWS library is not consistent.

2nd issue is, even if we pass the right key value pair, credentials utility stores all keys in lowercase letters. So, when we create credential provider with “fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId”, it stores as “fs.s3n.awsaccesskeyid”. So when we use that credential provider, it doesn’t find the right key as it still looking for a value for ”fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId”.

You will see the bug here: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common/2.7.1/org/apache/hadoop/security/alias/AbstractJavaKeyStoreProvider.java?av=f

There will be some work-around when we have https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-12548.